# Template and static variable

Tags: c++, object

I have made this  code to add numbers by adding first argument if you ask why i make it like

that because i will use it to solve a problem in my assignment the code works fine if the numbers are from the same data type for example int and int but if it is from different data types like double and int it no longer works as if static key word on m is not exist

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class first, class seconde>
void total (first a, seconde b){
    static first m =0 ;
    static seconde f=0;
    ++f;
    if(b==m){
        m+=a;
        cout<<m<<endl;
    }
        m+=a;
}

void main(){
    total(2,2);
    total(1,2);
    system("pause");
}
```

i need to know it dose not work with different data types when using int and double while iam using template

Comment: it will work fine if i put 2.1 and 2.5 not 2.1 and 2

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Each template specialisation will have its own static variables. If you want to share them between all specialisations, then you'll have to either make them global, or come up with a less nasty way to maintain state between function calls.

Comment: spiritwolfform no error message when different data types just null

Comment: Mike Seymour so why it works for same data types

Comment: Please define "does not work."

Comment: @user2918388: If you always use the same datatypes, then you always use the same specialisation, with the same static variables. If you sometimes use different datatypes, then you'll sometimes use different static variables.

Answer (score 3):

With templates, different template parameters creates a completely different and unrelated function.

Just remember that for every different combination of `first` and `seconde` you will have different `static` variables. Each different combo of template parameters generates a new function, so calling

```
total(1, 2) // calls total<int, int>
```

and

```
total(1, 1.3) // calls total<int, double> , a totally different function
```

will not access the same static variables.

Comment: they access the same one if they are of same data types you can try it

Comment: @user2918388 I know, but you said your problem was when you used it with different data types. I just told you why.

Comment: okay thank you but why that behavior when different combination

Comment: @user2918388 because they're two different functions. Each different combo of types makes a new function unrelated to the others. They don't share static variables. `total<int, int>` and `total<int, double>` are so unrelated that they might as well be named `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: @uk4321 +1 (both answer and comment). I'd just add that even `total<double, int>` is absolutely unrelated to `total<int, double>` (and all the others).

Comment: but wait why f remains the same during two function calling

Comment: @user2918388 because it is a completely different `f`. There are two `f`s and two `m`s if you do `total(1, 2)` and `total(1, 1.2)`. Because they call different functions. If you do `total(1, 2) total(3, 4)` they will call the same function twice with different arguments. One function total. But `total(1, 2) total(1, 1.1)` will call one function once and a different one once. Two functions total.

Comment: so what do you think i have to find new idea or try to modifey

Comment: @user2918388 yeah, I think you'll have to find a new idea.